# How to overlap other controls when changing height trough animation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I wanto to overlap other controls when changing the height of an other control. It should be something like when you pull up a view.

I created a little example:

[image]

And when i press on the blue button it goes up:

[image]

But the other controls just get smaler. I would like to "overlap" so that the red box would be not visible anymore, only after i make the blue box smal again.

Thats the Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Animated, TouchableOpacity, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export const IMAGE_HEIGHT = 50;
export const IMAGE_HEIGHT_SMALL = 500;


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.moveAnimation = new Animated.Value(50)
  }

  _changeHeight = () => {
    Animated.spring(this.moveAnimation, {
      duration: 50,
      toValue:IMAGE_HEIGHT_SMALL,
    }).start()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'red', alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
          <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
            <Text>Das ist einer Text in gelb</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
            <Text>Das ist einer Text in rot</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.panel, {height:this.moveAnimation}]}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton} onPress={this._changeHeight}>
                <Text style={{textAlign:'center'}}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  panel:{
    height:50, 
    justifyContent :'flex-end', 
    backgroundColor:'blue', 
    alignSelf: 'stretch'
  },
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
    flex:1
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it, there is position:'absolute'